# css to stylus scrollbar issue

Tags: css, scrollbar, stylus

I'm having difficulty translating some css to stylus. In my html/css tests it works absolutely fine, but when I try to rewrite it in jade and stylus I'm having some issues with proper syntax. For context I'm making a custom scrollbar.
Here's the css that I'm trying to change:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    background: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

Essentially the `body::-webkit-scrollbar`etc. lines, how would I change that over to working stylus?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I don't completely catch the problem that you're trying to solve. You can paste this code into a `.styl` file without any change and it will compile fine (without errors). But if you need more Stylus-way of writing it, you can write something like this:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar
  width: 12px
  background: rgba(0,0,255,1)

  &-track
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(255,0,0,1)

  &-thumb
    background-color: cornflowerblue
```

Answer (score 0):

The overflow property tells the browser how to handle content that overflows the display area of an element. The default value of this property, visible, tells the browser to render all content, making it visible even if it falls outside of the element's display area.

Erring on the side of caution, you most often want the browser to display all of your document's contents. But in rare cases, elements may overlap, creating an ugly display. To prevent such mishaps, set the overflow property to either hidden, scroll, or auto.

The hidden value forces the browser to hide all content that overflows its allotted space, making it invisible to the user. The value scroll creates scroll bars for the element, which viewers may use to see the hidden content. However, scroll bars are added to the element even if the content does not overflow.

Adding permanent scroll bars ensures that the scroll bars do not come and go as the content of the element changes in size in a dynamic document. The downside to this is the clutter and distractions that scroll bars create. Avoid all this with the auto value for the overflow property. When on auto, scroll bars appear only when they are needed. If the element's content changes so that it is not clipped, the scroll bars are removed from the element.

Comment: Alright I'll defiantly keep an eye out for that. This is just a snippet of the css file, so there is more than just these parts. But thanks for the good advice!